# Can we compile a Java program inside an applet or a Swing window

Tags: java, swing, compilation, applet

Can we run a Java program in an applet window or a Swing window and how can we see the output of the compiled program?

Comment: 1) In the title is says 'compile', in the post it says 'run'?  Is it the 1st, the 2nd or both?  2) An applet can (and should) be Swing based.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Compiler API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) (available in Java 6) to compile sources.

You can either exec() the new process (if it has a main() entry) point, or use classloading to load it into your JVM. Note that if you take the latter course, you'll likely have to instantiate a new classloader each time - see [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/ReloadClass.html) for more details.

You may have security concerns re. accessing the file system from an applet. As such you *may* be better off just using a standard Swing application (perhaps loaded using Java Web Start?)

Comment: exactly what I was going to type when I saw "compile a java program inside an applet"

Answer (score 2):

Re. JavaCompiler API & Applet or Swing launched with JWS.

To compile source supplied in a text area, or by URL from the code-base would not require trust.  OTOH the `JavaCompiler` is only available if the code is running in the JVM of a JDK (it requires the `tools.jar` to be on the run-time class-path).  Applets and JWS based apps. are never run using a JDK and never have the `tools.jar` available.

### See also

- [Example code for java compiler with a simple GUI](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1187455)  code & discussion at OTN.
- [STBC](http://pscode.org/stbc/) (based on that code).
- [STBC Help](http://pscode.org/stbc/help.html).  Goes into more detail on the `tools.jar` and the run-time class-path.

### Example code

To avoid 'link rot', here is the code seen in that linked thread.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
 
import java.util.ArrayList;
 
import java.net.URI;
 
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
 
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.SimpleJavaFileObject;
 
/** A simple Java compiler with a GUI.  Java 1.6+.
@author Andrew Thompson
@version 2008-06-13
*/
public class GuiCompiler extends JPanel {
 
  /** Instance of the compiler used for all compilations. */
  JavaCompiler compiler;
 
  /** The name of the public class.  For 'HelloWorld.java',
  this would be 'HelloWorld'. */
  JTextField name;
  /** The source code to be compiled. */
  JTextArea sourceCode;
  /** Errors and messages from the compiler. */
  JTextArea output;
 
  JButton compile;
 
  static int pad = 5;
 
  GuiCompiler() {
    super( new BorderLayout(pad,pad) );
    setBorder( new EmptyBorder(7,4,7,4) );
  }
 
  /** A worker to perform each compilation. Disables
  the GUI input elements during the work. */
  class SourceCompilation extends SwingWorker<String, Object> {
    @Override
    public String doInBackground() {
      return compileCode();
    }
 
    @Override
    protected void done() {
      try {
        enableComponents(true);
      } catch (Exception ignore) {
      }
    }
  }
 
  /** Construct the GUI. */
  public void initGui() {
    JPanel input = new JPanel( new BorderLayout(pad,pad) );
    Font outputFont = new Font("Monospaced",Font.PLAIN,12);
 
    sourceCode = new JTextArea("Paste code here..", 15, 60);
    sourceCode.setFont( outputFont );
    input.add( new JScrollPane( sourceCode ),
      BorderLayout.CENTER );
    sourceCode.select(0,sourceCode.getText().length());
 
    JPanel namePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(pad,pad));
    name = new JTextField(15);
    name.setToolTipText("Name of the public class");
    namePanel.add( name, BorderLayout.CENTER );
    namePanel.add( new JLabel("Class name"), BorderLayout.WEST );
 
    input.add( namePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH );
 
    compile = new JButton( "Compile" );
    compile.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
          (new SourceCompilation()).execute();
        }
      } );
    input.add( compile, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
 
    this.add( input, BorderLayout.CENTER );
 
    output = new JTextArea("", 5, 40);
    output.setFont( outputFont );
    output.setEditable(false);
    this.add( new JScrollPane( output ), BorderLayout.SOUTH );
  }
 
  /** Compile the code in the source input area. */
  public String compileCode() {
    output.setText( "Compiling.." );
    enableComponents(false);
    String compResult = null;
    if (compiler==null) {
      compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    }
    if ( compiler!=null ) {
      String code = sourceCode.getText();
      String sourceName = name.getText().trim();
      if ( sourceName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".java") ) {
        sourceName = sourceName.substring(
          0,sourceName.length()-5 );
      }
      JavaSourceFromString javaString = new JavaSourceFromString(
        sourceName,
        code);
      ArrayList<JavaSourceFromString> al =
        new ArrayList<JavaSourceFromString>();
      al.add( javaString );
 
      ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter( baos );
 
      JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(
        osw,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        al);
 
      boolean success = task.call();
 
      output.setText( baos.toString().replaceAll("\t", "  ") );
      compResult = "Compiled without errors: " + success;
      output.append( compResult );
      output.setCaretPosition(0);
    } else {
      output.setText( "No compilation possible - sorry!" );
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
        "No compiler is available to this runtime!",
        "Compiler not found",
        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE
        );
      System.exit(-1);
    }
    return compResult;
  }
 
  /** Set the main GUI input components enabled
  according to the enable flag. */
  public void enableComponents(boolean enable) {
    compile.setEnabled(enable);
    name.setEnabled(enable);
    sourceCode.setEnabled(enable);
  }
 
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
 
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("SSCCE text based compiler");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
 
        GuiCompiler compilerPane = new GuiCompiler();
        compilerPane.initGui();
 
        f.getContentPane().add(compilerPane);
 
        f.pack();
        f.setMinimumSize( f.getSize() );
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
      }
    };
    EventQueue.invokeLater(r);
  }
}
 
/**
* A file object used to represent source coming from a string.
* This example is from the JavaDocs for JavaCompiler.
*/
class JavaSourceFromString extends SimpleJavaFileObject {
  /**
  * The source code of this "file".
  */
  final String code;
 
  /**
  * Constructs a new JavaSourceFromString.
  * @param name the name of the compilation unit represented
    by this file object
  * @param code the source code for the compilation unit
    represented by this file object
  */
  JavaSourceFromString(String name, String code) {
    super(URI.create(
      "string:///" +
      name.replace('.','/') +
      Kind.SOURCE.extension),
      Kind.SOURCE);
    this.code = code;
  }
 
  @Override
  public CharSequence getCharContent(boolean ignoreEncodingErrors) {
    return code;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Java Compiler API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) to translate source code into bytecode. After that use [dynamic class loading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) to load compiled bytecode into jvm and launch it (to get output). 
Also, if you want to do this from inside of java applet, you'll have to solve security issues.

Answer (score 0):

Well applet is program which runs in background.For compiling a java program you'll need to access the local disk of client which `IS NOT ALLOWED` for an applet(According to my knowledge) due to security reasons. 
What are you trying to achieve? I once tried to access a img file using applet.

Comment: http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3303561/Creating-a-Trusted-Applet-with-Local-File-System-Access-Rights.htm You can.

Comment: can we access the local disk using swings.